# How to show the output of script bash in textview as list in java?

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to execute bash commands and all is fine in that just when I execute it the displayed output appears like paragraph and not list.
Before it was without line split, I tried to split string lines so below is my result, and this is my code:

```java
String[] cmdline = { "sh", "-c", "ls /storage/emulated/0/" }; 
    
try {
    java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String linee = "";
    while ((linee = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        int count = 1;
        String[] lines = linee.split("\\r?\\n");
    
        for (String line : lines) {
            result.append("line " + count++ + " : " + line);
        }
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    tv.setText(result.toString());
    
} catch (Exception s) {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Please help me edit this code so that the result appears one below one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns a single line of text without a line break, so

```
String[] lines = linee.split("\\r?\\n");
```

always returns an array of length 1 containing `linee`. You should remove this code.

---

Second: your line counter `count` is reset to 1 after each line read, so your output will always contain "line 1: ", no matter how many lines you read.

Move that count variable outside of the `while` loop to correct this.

---

Third: You are appending the lines to `result` without line breaks between, so all you get is a single paragraph.

Add a line break character ("\n") to correct this.

---

In the end the central part of your code should look like this:

```
StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
String line;
int count = 1;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append("line " + (count++) + " : " + line + "\n");
}
```